# Apache Solr & schema.xml

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

I have just began with Apache Solr 4.1 yesterday and though I have managed to get our MySQL data imported successfully in Solr, I am unable to view any data using queries. I suspect the problem is in schema.xml changes (data-config.xml is correct). Here are my questions -

- Do I need to add all DB fields in the schema.xml? My table has 275+
  fields, and configuring all of them would be a task. I am hoping
  there is a way to auto-configure these fields.
- Is there a way to use separate schema.xml for my requirement? Where
  and how do I configure this? I don't want to modify the example-DIH's
  sample schema.xml

Any pointers here would be highly appreciated! I have already gone through this document - 
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

and I have also read few question posted here, but couldn't find answer to my queries.

Answer (score 1):

1) All the fields that you are mentioning in data-config.xml as field column must add them to schema.xml. No auto-configure is available.
2) No we cannot use separate schema.xml.

Could you please show some of your indexed field that you have mentioned in schema.xml

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @Jayesh. I have not added any field explicitly in data-config.xml and my first query is just basic "select * from table_name".

I think my fields are perhaps conflicting with Solr examples, so I am writing my own new schema.xml now based on the example-DIH. 

Not having different/separate schema.xml hurts, probably I will  need to have my own different cores. 

I will post here how it goes. Thanks again for your useful inputs.

Comment: No need to have different cores. You can modify the existing schema.xml to have your fields. No need to remove existing fields as well.

Comment: @Manish Any success on this Manish?

Comment: @JayeshBhoyar: Hi, I too just started with solr. I installed the PECL PHP extension of `solr` and it works. I had a doubt though. How do I link my schema.xml etc. files with the `php` files?

Comment: @JayeshBhoyar: For example, if we are not using `solr` to index documents, then will `schema.xml` change in any way? I mean in that case, we have to follow the steps as we follow when indexing is through `solr`? [not regarding whether/or not using php]